# Меняется вывод на сайте pythontutor

Tags: python, словари

Решая задачу на [питонтьюторе](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/dicts/problems/english_latin_dict/) столкнулся с проблемой ,у меня меняется вывод после отправления решения на сайт, в jupiter notebook и в [pythontutor live programming mode](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) все выводится как и должно. Не могу понять в чем ошибка

Задача:

Однажды, разбирая старые книги на чердаке, школьник Вася нашёл англо-латинский словарь. Английский он к тому времени знал в совершенстве, и его мечтой было изучить латынь. Поэтому попавшийся словарь был как раз кстати.

К сожалению, для полноценного изучения языка недостаточно только одного словаря: кроме англо-латинского необходим латинско-английский. За неимением лучшего он решил сделать второй словарь из первого.

Как известно, словарь состоит из переводимых слов, к каждому из которых приводится несколько слов-переводов. Для каждого латинского слова, встречающегося где-либо в словаре, Вася предлагает найти все его переводы (то есть все английские слова, для которых наше латинское встречалось в его списке переводов), и считать их и только их переводами этого латинского слова.

Помогите Васе выполнить работу по созданию латинско-английского словаря из англо-латинского.

В первой строке содержится единственное целое число N — количество английских слов в словаре. Далее следует N описаний. Каждое описание содержится в отдельной строке, в которой записано сначала английское слово, затем отделённый пробелами дефис, затем разделённые запятыми с пробелами переводы этого английского слова на латинский. Все слова состоят только из маленьких латинских букв. Переводы отсортированы в лексикографическом порядке. Порядок следования английских слов в словаре также лексикографический.

Выведите соответствующий данному латинско-английский словарь, в точности соблюдая формат входных данных. В частности, первым должен идти перевод лексикографически минимального латинского слова, далее — второго в этом порядке и т.д. Внутри перевода английские слова должны быть также отсортированы лексикографически.

В моем решении в jupiter notebook вывод с данными от первого примера дает таким:

Ввод:

```
3
apple - malum, pomum, popula
fruit - baca, bacca, popum
punishment - malum, multa
```

Вывод(jupiter notebook):

```
7
baca - fruit
bacca - fruit
malum - apple,punishment
multa - punishment
pomum - apple
popula - apple
popum - fruit
```

Вывод (pythontutor):

```
7
popum - fruit
popula - apple
pomum - apple
multa - punishment
malum - apple,punishment
bacca - fruit
baca - fruit
```

Сама программа:

```
eng_lat = {}
sinonims = []

for i in range(int(input())):
    eng, *lat = input().replace(',', '').split()
    lat.remove('-')
    for word in lat:
        if word in sinonims:
            eng_lat[word].append(eng)
            sinonims.append(word)
        else:
            sinonims.append(word)
            eng_lat[word] = [eng]

d = {k: v for k, v in sorted(eng_lat.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])}

print(len(eng_lat))

for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, ','.join(v), sep=' - ')
```

Comment: Видимо, версии питона разные. С какой-то версии (кажется, 3.7) порядок элементов в словаре сохраняется, а до того он был не гарантирован.

Comment: и еще - судя по всему, для верного ответа вам надо сортировать и список слов для каждого ключа